# Why is my DLL slower when compiled with Visual Studio 2022 (v143) compared to Visual Studio 2012 Express (v110)? It is connected to GAMS

Tags: visual-studio, dll, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gams-math

I'm a phd student working in the field of mathematical optimization of chemical plants. Currently, I am working on optimization models in GAMS (General Algebraic Modeling System) which utilize some external functions written in C and incorporated to the GAMS model as DLL. The original version of these external functions were compiled in VS 2012 Express with the platform toolset v110. This setup leads to a fast speed and a good solution in the GAMS model. Now, I tried to update the project to the newest toolset v143. The compilation in VS 2022 Community worked just fine but I get not the same results in GAMS and the time to converge the optimization is up to 40 times slower (from about 20s to 14 minutes).

I already tried to compare the settings of the projects but there seems to be no difference. I also just copied the 2012 project folder, opened it in VS 2022, and updated to the newest toolset. The result stays the same and I am puzzled what happens here. Both projects are compiled as x64 in release mode.

Additionally, I tried to do the same in VS 2019 Community (v142) resulting in the same flaws (slow, poor results). A big problem here is that I cannot use a debug version when running the code with GAMS to see intermediate results and running times. There are some manually implemented debug flags but it is hard to compare tens of thousands of lines of code in this way when you don't know what to look for.

I am grateful for any tips and I know this post is pretty vague and does lack some information. Please ask for additional information. But I can already say that I can't share the source code and unfortunately there is no possibility of a simple demonstration example.

Comment: I think I would start adding some logging to the DLL and see if the two versions give the same result for the same input.

Comment: I will definitely try that and see if there are any flaws in the different calculation steps. But this will result in a long trial and error procedure. I was hoping that someone already faced a similar problem when changing to newer compiler versions. Nonetheless, thank you very much for your answer!